# Is it possible to add textfield component as a tree item in Material Tree View

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am creating a material UI Tree View component,.Here my Tree is having few tree items as children. My goal is I will be able to update the name of the children.So I tried to use the text field component inside tree item tag.But it didn't work. 
Could anyone help me how to rename its children?
In other words, I need an editable Tree.

Here I have used Textfied like below.

```
const  item = <TextField
name="Application"
label="Application" readOnly={false}></TextField>;
 <TreeItem nodeId="2" label={item} />
```

My Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
  },
});

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  const classes = useStyles();
const  item = <TextField
name="Application"
label="Application" readOnly={false}></TextField>;
  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
       defaultExpanded={["1"]}
    >

      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Application">

        <TreeItem nodeId="2" label={item} />
        <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="4" label="Webstorm" />
      </TreeItem>
      <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents">
        <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="Material-UI">
          <TreeItem nodeId="7" label="src">
            <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
            <TreeItem nodeId="9" label="tree-view.js" />
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems okay. What exactly "didn't work"?

Here's a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-with-textfield-sde8y

Here's my code in case I delete that sandbox later:

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: "4px 8px"
  }
});

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("Custom item");

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
        <TreeItem
          nodeId="2"
          label={
            <TextField
              value={value}
              variant="outlined"
              InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.inputInput } }}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          }
        />
        <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="4" label="Webstorm" />
      </TreeItem>
      <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents">
        <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="Material-UI">
          <TreeItem nodeId="7" label="src">
            <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
            <TreeItem nodeId="9" label="tree-view.js" />
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```